# though jQuery .toggle() dropdown (less than 991px width)

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, menu, submenu

I am trying to toggle a menu/submenu for smaller screens. (max-width: 991px) When you click the "product" link, the `.dropdown` menu should show, and when the "`accessories`" link is selected, the `.subdropdown` class should show. It would be nice to tap anywhere off of the menus to release them at any depth.

Note: On screens `min-width: 991px` (desktop), the `:hover` will come into play.

Notice how my JavaScript code will not fire the sub "`accessories`" menu. You will have to refresh if you resize your window to test.

Here is the live example: [Click Here](http://www.lestaylordesign.com/contract)

Here is my js code

```
$(function() {

    if ($(window).width() < 991) {

        $('#product-link').click(function() {
            $('.dropdown').toggle();
        });

        if ('.dropdown' === true) {
            $('#accessories-link').click(function() {
                $('.subdropdown').show();
            });
        } else {
            $('.dropdown').hide();
        }
    }

});
```

Edit: 
Although not perfect, it works. I am still wanting to use .click and not .hover but this gets the job done.

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.top-menu').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).children('.sub-menu').fadeIn(200);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).children('.sub-menu').fadeOut(200);
        }
    );
})`

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement is going to always evaluate to false.

Line 9: `if ('.dropdown' === true)`

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery you are setting up event listeners on specific elements however your current setup is not taking advantage of the on method for your product-link. Try switching your code up to something like

```
$(function() {
    $('#product-link').on('click mouseover', function(){
        $('.dropdown').toggle();
        if($('#product-link').hasClass('.dropdown')){
            //something else here 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the code but it wasn't quite what I am going for. I'm wanting this to be a mobile first approach for screens 991 and below. No mouse over. 

I want my code to run only if the screen size is less than 991px. 
`if ($(window).width() < 991)`

Also... I cant figure out how to fire the .subdropdown class when accessories is clicked.